# can't run alias command on shell script despite source bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, alias, google-closure-compiler

I have this alias on my `~/.bashrc`

`alias closure-compiler="java -jar ~/bin/closure-compiler-v20190325.jar"`

when I run `closure-compiler` on console it works.

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

source ~/.bashrc

closure-compiler --js $orig --js_output_file $comp
```

when I run this it complains

```
source: not found
closure-compiler: not found
```

Comment: Did you mean `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Your script is currently a `sh` script and not a `bash` script. You have to update your `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`. You can then use the solution from the duplicate